# How to Async Mongoose Controller

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Trying to configure a `SignUp()` controller that can update multiple (separate) user accounts when a referral code is provided by the user.

*Basic Flow:*

1. Verify email doesn't already exist in system
2. Find the driver w/ `userID` matching the rider's `refCode` (FindOneAndUpdate)
3. If Found: Add the `userID` of each user to the other users `[clients]` list
4. Only need to do a refCode match if `isRider`
5. If any of those fail... Return the *specific error* to the client/user

*This does not work. But essentially, this is what I'm trying to accomplish...*

```
// POST `/signup` (Create a new local user)
export function signUp(req, res, next) {
  const newUser = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    profile: {
      userID: req.body.userID,
      refCode: req.body.refCode,
      isRider: req.body.isRider
    }
  });

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (findErr, foundUser) => {
    if (foundUser) {
      return res.status(409).send('This e-mail address already exists');
    }
    // riders must link to a driver
    if (req.body.isRider) {
      // find driver + add rider ID to clients
      return User.findOneAndUpdate({ 'profile.userID': req.body.refCode }, { $push: { clients: newUser.profile.userID }}).exec()
        .then((err, foundDriver) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(409).send('Error searching for driver');
          } else if (!foundDriver) {
            return res.status(409).send(`We can't find your driver (${req.body.refCode})!`);
          }
          // add driver ID to rider's clients
          newUser.clients = [req.body.refCode];

          return newUser.save((saveErr) => {
            if (saveErr) return next(saveErr);
            return req.logIn(newUser, (loginErr) => {
              if (loginErr) return res.sendStatus(401);
              return res.json(newUser.profile);
            });
          });
        });
    }

    return newUser.save((saveErr) => {
      if (saveErr) return next(saveErr);
      return req.logIn(newUser, (loginErr) => {
        if (loginErr) return res.sendStatus(401);
        return res.json(newUser.profile);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Tried to configure it as a pure promise but no luck. Most of the examples out there all seem different to me... Also could not figure out how to handle/throw specific errors using the mongoose docs.

Greatly appreciated if anyone can lend a hand, Thx!

---

**UPDATE:**
Ippi's answer helped a ton - Thx!

This does the trick. Remember to return `null` from `.then()` after the `req.login` stuff to avoid warnings - Any tips on how to improve this are appreciated - Thx!

```
  const createUser = (foundUser) => {
    if (foundUser) { throw new Error('This e-mail address already exist.'); }
    if (!req.body.isRider) { return newUser.save(); }
    return User.findOneAndUpdate({ 'profile.userID': req.body.refCode.toLowerCase() }, { $push: { clients: newUser.profile.userID }}).exec()
      .then((driver) => {
        if (!driver) { throw new Error('We can\'t find your driver.'); }
        newUser.clients = [req.body.refCode];
        return newUser.save();
      })
      .catch(() => { throw new Error('There was a database error.'); });
  };

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec()
    .then(createUser)
    .then((user) => {
      if (user.profile) {
        req.logIn(user, (loginErr) => {
          if (loginErr) return res.sendStatus(401);
          return res.status(200).send({ profile: user.profile, clients: user.clients });
        });
      } else { res.status(409); }
      return null;
    })
    .catch((err) => { return res.status(409).send(err.message); });
```

Comment: `.then((err, foundDriver)`   With promises, you never pass in the error. Instead last in your promise chain you use `.then(...).catch(err=>{...})`. And to what extent you can, try to not mix callbacks and promises. It'll make your world so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
function signUp(req, res, next) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        profile: {
            userID: req.body.userID,
            refCode: req.body.refCode,
            isRider: req.body.isRider
        }
    });

    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (findErr, foundUser) => {
        if (foundUser) {
            // return res.status(409).send('This e-mail address already exists');
            reject('This e-mail address already exists');
        }
        // riders must link to a driver
        if (req.body.isRider) {
            // find driver + add rider ID clients
            return User.findOneAndUpdate({ 'profile.userID': req.body.refCode }, { $push: { clients: newUser.profile.userID } }).exec()
                .then((err, foundDriver) => {
                    if (err) {
                        // return res.status(409).send('Error searching for driver');
                        reject('Error searching for driver');
                    } else if (!foundDriver) {
                        // return res.status(409).send(`We can't find your driver (${req.body.refCode})!`);
                        reject(`We can't find your driver (${req.body.refCode})!`);
                    }
                    // add driver ID to rider's clients
                    newUser.clients = [req.body.refCode];

                    newUser.save((saveErr) => {
                        if (saveErr)
                            // next(saveErr);
                            reject(saveErr);
                        req.logIn(newUser, (loginErr) => {
                            if (loginErr)
                                // return res.sendStatus(401);
                                reject('401');
                            // return res.json(newUser.profile);
                            resolve(newUser.profile);
                        });
                    });
                });
        }

        newUser.save((saveErr) => {
            if (saveErr)
                // return next(saveErr);
                reject(saveErr);
            req.logIn(newUser, (loginErr) => {
                if (loginErr)
                    // return res.sendStatus(401);
                    reject(loginErr);
                // return res.json(newUser.profile);
                resolve(newUser.profile);
            });
        });
    });

});}
```

Comment: +1 for the effort. Though I'd still `exec` the first findOne-query to get a promise, chain the results, remove the err-parameter from functions called by `.then()`, use the promise returned from `save()` (twice) and use .catch to handle errors. And I think wrapping the whole thing in a new promise is nonsense! (sorry)

Comment: That's definitely what I want to do, set the whole thing up as a chained promise... However, the system I'm using is not expecting a Promise to be returned (controller: https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo/blob/77abc22da04c634fac912e136a39e079029569a3/server/db/mongo/controllers/users.js, react action: https://github.com/reactGo/reactGo/blob/77abc22da04c634fac912e136a39e079029569a3/app/actions/users.js)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. I couldn't be bothered to try with express or the login (you need to replace `console.log` with `res.status().json()`) and I might have done some other blunder in the logic with the driver. But other than that I tested it with local mongo and it probably works and if nothing else it's a little bit more concise.

```
let updateUser = user => {
  if (user){ throw new Error("USER_EXIST"); }
  if (!req.body.isRider) { return newUser.save() }
  return User.findOneAndUpdate({ 'profile.userID': req.body.refCode },{ $push: { clients: newUser.profile.userID }}).exec()
    .then(driver => {
      if (!driver) { throw new Error("NO_DRIVER");}
      newUser.clients.push(req.body.refCode);
      return newUser.save();
    });
}

User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec()
  .then(updateUser)
  .then(req.logIn) // newUser.save() response is passed in as is (I have not tested this line.)
  .then( ()=>{ return console.log('profile', newUser.profile);  })
  .catch( Error,  err => {
    if (err.message == "USER_EXISTS") return console.log ("This e-mail address already exist." );
    if (err.message == "NO_DRIVER") return console.log ("We can't find your driver." );
      throw err;
  });
```

Something worth remembering:

- Callback calls or res.send should always go in the last then / catch. Calling res.send in middle of chains leads to trouble.

Comment: Oh, and I use bluebird, not sure how it plays in; `mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');`